# How do you list all smb servers on the network?

Tags: java, android, samba, smb, jcifs

Is it possible using jcifs to list all smb servers available on the network? I tried a suggestion on another post of passing `smb://` to the `SmbFile` constructor but that didn't give me any results. Whereas I am able to pass `smb://username:password@machinename` and that works fine. Other computers are able to find `machinename` without problems and even another Android app is able to see it using `SMB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of servers is not available through the SMB protocol itself. To receive such a list the client must implement LSA and SAMR protocols. Both are DCERPC pipes. JCIFS features a generic DCERPC framework but, as far as I know, it does not implement the required LSA and SAMR. Alternative SMB clients: smbclient, NQE and jNQ do implement these calls.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful.